# Disable an ng-click on an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've read through a bunch of questions on SO and for whatever reason the solutions posted are not working. I have a list of items that I'm `ng-repeat`ing, and I want to disable two items from being clicked.

```
<tr ng-repeat="itm in jtc.jobTypes" ng-click="jtc.showAdvanced(itm); setSelected(itm.JobTypeId)" ng-disabled="itm.JobTypeId==-1" ng-class="{selected: itm.JobTypeId === idSelected}">
```

Comment: You can't use a conditional in ng tags, you can do this check in the ng-click callback, check using an argument variable for example or use de index of ng-repeat and don't do whatever ng-click callback is doing for that condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only form elements (textbox, button, etc.) can have a `disabled` property set on them.

To disable a click event on a particular item, check your item ID inside the click handler.

```
showAdvanced(itm) {
  if (itm.JobTypeId != -1) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Further, you shouldn't be calling multiple functions in the `ng-click` handler. Make a separate click handler function and call the other functions from inside it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="itm in jtc.jobTypes" ng-click="onItemClicked(itm)">
```

And...

```
onItemClicked(item) {
  if (itm.JobTypeId != -1) {
    showAdvanced(itm);
    setSelected(itm.JobTypeId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **ng-class**

```
ng-class="(itm.JobTypeId==-1)?'disableClick':''"
```

**css**

```
.disableClick {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```